# Compile error with a template when building with GCC but not MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, syntax-error

On expression:

```
typedef RDOCalcUnary<RDOValue, (&RDOValue::operator-), OperatorType::OT_ARITHM> RDOCalcUMinus;
```

gcc shows the following errors:

> error: ‘rdoRuntime::RDOValue::operator-’ cannot appear in a
>   constant-expression
>
> error: ‘&’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
>
> error: template argument 2 is invalid
>
> error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token

Under Windows the MSVC compiler compiles the code without errors.

What's the problem? How do I fix this?

```
template <typename ret_type, ret_type (RDOValue::*pOperator)() const, typename OperatorType::Type CalcType>
class RDOCalcUnary: public RDOCalcUnaryBase
{
friend class rdo::Factory<RDOCalcUnary<ret_type, pOperator, CalcType> >;
public:
    enum { calc_type = CalcType };
    typedef ret_type (RDOValue::*value_operator)() const;

    static RDOSrcInfo     getStaticSrcInfo(CREF(RDOSrcInfo::Position) position, CREF(LPRDOCalc) pUnaryCalc);
    static value_operator getOperation    ();

protected:
    RDOCalcUnary(CREF(RDOSrcInfo::Position) position, CREF(LPRDOCalc) pOperation);

private:
    REF(RDOValue) doCalc(CREF(LPRDORuntime) pRuntime);
};
```

Comment: Can you paste the definition of `RDOCalcUnary` for us, so we know what the template parameters are supposed to be?  This code looks totally nonsensical to me...

Comment: What happens if you remove the parentheses? They shouldn't be needed, as far as I can tell

Comment: I removed the parentheses and the compiler no longer gives error ... let's see what will happen when I will gather the entire application. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the typedef don't use brackets:

```
typedef RDOCalcUnary<RDOValue, &RDOValue::operator-, OperatorType::OT_ARITHM> RDOCalcUMinus;
```

It works to me.